# Variable rc high pass filter

Tags: audio, filter

Hey there I’m new in this field please guide me as much as you willing to. Recently I’ve build the 3rd order high pass filter with RC circuit using a selector switch to send the audio signal to respective circuit to get the frequency cut off I desire. But I stuck in a problems where the highest the frequency seems getting quieter in the output comparing with the lower frequency point being cut. My question is how it’s possible to get all the output is relatively same for each output frequency I filter. What component and configuration should I use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Even a 2nd order filter might need two variable resistors to be swept, simultaneously. A 3rd order will need three of them. How do you suppose you can achieve that? There may be pots that are used for "stereo" applications (e.g. two pots in one case) but, 3 or more, I don't know. Plus, they aren't exactly cheap. What purpose is it for? Also, a schematic of how you implemented the filter and how you used it would help avoid assumptions.

Comment: Hey there thank you for replying to my question, so I would put different value of capacitor to determining frequency cut then each capacitor with different value goes to 22k resistor and there’s 3 of them and using switch selector is how I swept the frequency, so the switch will send the signal to different value of capacitor to get the filter from low to high, I using it for effects in mixing audio purposes. But the problem is I wanna equalise the output for each frequency output in my case is the higher I cut the quieter became the outputs.

Comment: @Biyn I think I am gathering that you want a have a variable cutoff frequency to your high pass filter. But I've no idea what you are otherwise on about because I don't see a diagram describing what you *are* doing. (And any high pass filter is really a band pass filter because of parasitics.) I think we need to see more detail. Lots more, if possible.